# USB 3.0 Flash Drive vs. 5400 rpm HDD for VirtualBox VM

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, multi-boot, usb-flash-drive

Based on a comment, I'm trying to make this a technical question rather than an opinion question--performance of two proposed hardware configurations.

I want to switch back and forth between Linux and Windows on my laptop. I'm doing some performance heavy processing that requires large files.

I benchmarked my 5400 RPM laptop HDD as such:

[image]

USB 3.0 flash drives claim to get many times that. I understand that there are various modes of read/write/seek and speeds vary depending on file size as well. Given the properties of the different storage devices, would there be any performance advantage to me running a VirtulBox VM from a flash drive VS my HDD?

Also, if I wanted to go dual boot, which would perform better, partition on my HDD or boot from USB?

Comment: you will wear out a flash drive (pen drive) fast running an os from it. Better off using an SSD.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean about opinion-based. I think I can rephrase it to be a question about performance expectations. That would make your answers appropriate--particularly about wearing out the USB with that kind of use.

Comment: @Moab Some manufacturers offer "lifetime warranties." Is that bogus? I guess it doesn't matter either way if I lose my data.

Comment: Thanks all--found this great explanation of USB Pendrive VS SSD: http://superuser.com/questions/919058/whats-the-technical-difference-between-a-flash-drive-and-an-ssd?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

Yes, a USB3 flash drive attached to a USB3 port would most certainly be faster than a 5400RPM hard drive.  I've run Windows-To-Go from a flash drive before, and the performance is on-par with being booted from the internal SSD.

HOWEVER...

You will also burn up that flash drive very quickly.  Virtual machines are very I/O intensive.  USB flash drives are not designed to handle that kind of load on a long-term basis the way SSDs are.